# How do I create an F# Type Provider for a generated assembly?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm having problems using any types created in an assembly for an F# Generative Type Provider. I created a [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/pq7ap8mrN18) that demonstrates this.

The error messages I get are:

- The module/namespace 'tutorial' from compilation unit 'Addressbook1' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'Person'
- A reference to the type 'tutorial.Person' in assembly 'Addressbook1' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly

I don't understand because the type is definitely in the assembly. For troubleshooting this, the assembly is a very basic C# dll. The code in the video is available via git:

git url: https://code.google.com/p/froto/
git branch: help

Any troubleshooting ideas would be appreciated. I'm hoping to make more progress on [an F# Type Provider for .proto files](http://blog.ctaggart.com/2012/11/1st-build-of-f-type-provider-for-proto.html), but I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Have you considered using the ProvidedTypes API from the F# 3 Sample Pack (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034.aspx)) rather than using the raw type provider API?

Answer (score 5):

I've taken a quick look at your code - as I mentioned in a comment I think you would be much better served by using the ProvidedTypes API that is defined by the F# 3.0 Sample Pack and documented (a bit) on MSDN.

Basically, the raw type provider API has a lot of assumptions baked in which will be hard for you to maintain by hand.  I think that the specific problem you have is that the compiler expects to see a type named `tutorial.Person` in your assembly (since it's the return type of a method on `tutorial.AddressbookProto`, which you are exposing as a generated type), but it isn't ever embedded into your assembly.

However, this is really only one of several problems - as you've probably realized, your will see additional errors if the type that you're defining is called anything other than `tutorial.AddressbookProto`.  That's because you're using a concrete type as the return from `ApplyStaticArguments`, but you would typically want to use a synthetic `System.Type` instance that accurately reflects the namespace and type name that the user used (e.g. in the ProvidedTypes API the `ProvidedTypeDefinition` class inherits from `System.Type` and handles this bookkeeping).

Comment: I have been looking at fsharpx's ProvidedTypes.fsi and ProvidedTypes.fs. What I don't understand is why the compiler can't find tutorial.Person. It is in the assembly returned from GetGeneratedAssemblyContents(assembly). (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.TypeProviders/)

Comment: The other problems you describe are simply because it is a simple test case. I'm returning a concrete type, but if you take a look at the master branch, you'll see that I'm generating the types in an assembly on the fly using Roslyn. The part that I'm stuck on is that F# doesn't find any of the other types from the generated assembly.

Comment: The compiler only looks at the types returned by provided namespaces (with static arguments applied to those types, if necessary), and any types nested within them.  That's why it doesn't find the Person type.

Comment: So, how do I provide the tutorial.Person type in this simple case? I believe I must create a new IProvidedNamespace for "tutorial" and then return a Type representing Person from GetTypes(). I will look at the ProvidedTypes.fs some more. It looks like the ProvidedAssembly and ProvidedTypeDefinition may be able to help out here.

Comment: @CameronTaggart - I think that the typical pattern would be to have the type returned by your type provider be a container type, and then nest both AddressBook and Person under that.